# Setting MySQL SQL Modes to be stricter before migrating to SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-migration

We're eventually migrating an application to SQL Server 2008, but before we do that, we're considering setting the MySQL SQL modes to be stricter so that we can test the "looseness" of the existing application before it's migrated to the stricter SQL Server 2008.

What are some MySQL SQL modes we can set in order to get it to be more at the strictness level of SQL Server 2008 to help better facilitate the migration eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start would be the mode

[MSSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_mssql)

This enables: `PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ANSI_QUOTES, IGNORE_SPACE, NO_KEY_OPTIONS, NO_TABLE_OPTIONS, NO_FIELD_OPTIONS, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`

Some others that caught my attention while looking through the list of modes where:

[`PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pad_char_to_full_length) and [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

I would also try to import the data into SQLServer 2008 and run queries against both while developing in MySQL.